# Distribution of a rate in a subsample after permutation of the total dataset

Tags: distributions, subsampling, permutation

I need to estimate the distribution of a rate in a subsample after permutation of the total dataset. I was wondering whether it's sufficient to use the binomial distribution with the global rate conditional on the subsample size, or the fact that the randomness comes from permutation makes the binomial not correct in this care.

To be more explicit:
From the dataset $D$ of length, $N$ with $pN$ positives and $(1-p)N$ negatives randomly ordered, take the first $n$ cases and report the $p_{sub} = pos/n$. Then permute the dataset $D$ and repeat $T$ times to acquire a distribution of $p_{sub}$.
Is there an analytical approximation $f$ so that $p_{sub} \sim f(n, p)$?

Comment: This is the *hypergeometric distribution.*

Comment: It's definitely that! thanks!